# CSS fixed fixed float layout

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a searchbox with label filters tucked to the left of the box, my markup looks something like this:

```
  <div id="searchbox">
    <div class="filter"> filter 1 </div>
    <div class="filter"> filter 2 </div>
    <input id="input" value="search query">
  </div>
```

I put one of my attempts in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nSDV9/7/

I want the input element to use all the remaining space in the searchbox, regardless of the number of filter elements tucked to the left of it (including zero). I have tried to apply the float/overflow:hidden/etc. tricks I could find, but I haven't been able to get the effect I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/nSDV9/9/

Html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="filter"> filter 1 </div>
    <div class="filter"> filter 2 </div>
<div class="searchwrap">
    <input id="searchbox" value="search query">
    </div>   
</div>
```

Css:

```
#container{
 width: 500px;   
 background: red;
 overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.searchwrap{
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
}

.filter{
    float:left;
     background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#searchbox {
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    background: yellow;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/nSDV9/8/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="filter"> filter 1 </div>
    <div class="filter"> filter 2 </div>
    <div class="search-container"><input id="searchbox" value="search query"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
    width: 500px;   
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.filter{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 4px;
}
#searchbox {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the box-sizing trick, but if possible I'd rather use a non-CSS3 solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cleanest I could make:

http://jsfiddle.net/nSDV9/11/

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the effect I want.

Comment: Why not? It fills the remaining space, adapting to the divs on the left.